# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mqjbnd05 (Not found in java.library.path) error in Java program for IBM MQ Binding Connection

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Problem Description :

I have installed MQ Server and MQ Client both with version 9.0. I have defined a Queue Manager and Queues and Topics. I am using Java 7. I have developed a standalone java client to connect to the Queue Manager in **BINDING mode**. The java application and MQ are being hosted on the same server, so BINDING connection has its necessary pre-requisites.

However when I am trying to run my application I am getting an error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mqjbnd05 (Not found in java.library.path)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1279)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1245)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:540)
at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.loadLib(MQSESSION.java:872).....
```

Have searched a few topics related to this but couldn't find any definite solution. I am pasting my java code below :

```
/**
* 
*/
package com.binding;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Session;    
import com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage;
import com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueReceiver;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSender;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession;

/**
* @author Som
*
*/
public class MQBindingConnection {

/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

try {
      MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();

      // Config
      //cf.setHostName("localhost");
      //cf.setPort(1414);
      cf.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_BINDINGS_MQ);
      cf.setQueueManager("QM.E001");
      //cf.setChannel("SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN");

      MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection("user","pass");
      MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("BINDING.CONN");
      MQQueueSender sender =  (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);
      MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) session.createReceiver(queue);      

      long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
      JMSTextMessage message = (JMSTextMessage) session.createTextMessage("SimplePTP "+ uniqueNumber);     

      // Start the connection
      connection.start();

      sender.send(message);
      System.out.println("Sent message:\\n" + message);

      JMSMessage receivedMessage = (JMSMessage) receiver.receive(10000);
      System.out.println("\\nReceived message:\\n" + receivedMessage);

      sender.close();
      receiver.close();
      session.close();
      connection.close();

      System.out.println("\\nSUCCESS\\n");
    }
    catch (JMSException jmsex) {
      System.out.println(jmsex);
      System.out.println("\\nFAILURE\\n");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
      System.out.println("\\nFAILURE\\n");
    }

    }

}
```

I could not find the file "mqjbnd05" in the directory location : ***C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib***
Also in lib64 path I have checked but the file is missing. ***C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib64***

I have set my CLASSPATH variable to point to the correct MQ lib directory.

I have tried changing the lib directory location to both server and client, however, the file **"mqjbnd05"** is missing everywhere, so as expected same error is encountered.

The same piece of code using the commented out sections is running fine for **CLIENT mode**.Please let me know what else I am missing out for connecting in **BINDING mode**.

I am using the following ENV variables :

```
MQ_JAVA_LIB_PATH = C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib64;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib    
MQ_FILE_PATH = C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ    
MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH = C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ   
MQ_JAVA_INSTALL_PATH = C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java    
MQ_JRE_PATH = C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\jre    
LIB = C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\lib64;C:\IBM\SQLLIB\LIB;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\lib    
CLASSPATH = C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib\com.ibm.mqjms.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib\com.ibm.mq.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib64;
```

One thing to add is : I have the file **mqjbnd.dll** but not the **mqjbnd05**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mqjbnd05 was removed from the MQ product in MQ v7, prefering instead to use a generic mqjbnd with an interface which worked across subsequent releases. However, that means if you are running a Java application and picking up MQ v6 or earlier jar files, but with an MQ product install of post-MQv6 then you will get the error you report. There are no references I can find to mqjbnd05 in the MQv9 codebase.

Given you said in a comment you have mqjbnd.dll and MQServer+MQClient v9, then the only way I can think of to achieve this is either you are picking up jars from pre-MQv7 from the classpath, or that you have build your application and included within your application the MQ jars themsevles.

Depending on how you run your application, you could try adding the -verbose option to the java launch to see where the MQ jars are coming from.

Comment: @Som to add to what JasonE said, your `CLASSPATH` does not indicate you have any directories other than the directories that would be installed with MQ v9.  Check for any com.ibm.*.jar files included in your application jar file or project.  If you find any check the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file and look for `Implementation-Version`, this will tell you want version of MQ the jar file is from.  You should remove references to this older MQ jar file from your application and let it pick up the current jar files that you have listed in your `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: @JasonE :   Hello Jason, Yes you are correct. I was using a older version of com.ibm.mq.jar  and   com.ibm.mqjms.jar. I have replaced them with the ones that came from MQ v9.0 product. And my code is running successfully now. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

JoshMc : Yes you are correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Som I would recommend to just let the jar files be picked up from the CLASSPATH pointing to the MQ install location, this way you will always pick up the version matching what is installed on the server.